# How to update multiple rows using Hector

Tags: cassandra, hector

Is there a way I can update multiple rows in cassandra database using column family template like supply a list of keys.
currently I am using updater columnFamilyTemplate to loop through a list of a keys and do an update for each row. I have seen queries like multigetSliceQuery but I don't know their equivalence in doing updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no utility method in ColumnFamilyTemplate that allow you to just pass a list of keys with a list of mutation in one call.
You can implement your own using mutators.

This is the basic code on how to do it in hector

```
Set<String> keys = MY_KEYS;
Map<String, String> pairsOfNameValues = MY_MUTATION_BY_NAME_AND_VALUE;

Set<HColumn<String, String>> colums = new HashSet<HColumn<String,String>>();
for (Entry<String, String> pair : pairsOfNameValues.entrySet()) {
    colums.add(HFactory.createStringColumn(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue()));
}

Mutator<String> mutator = template.createMutator();
String column_family_name = template.getColumnFamily();
for (String key : keys) {
    for (HColumn<String, String> column : colums) {
        mutator.addInsertion(key, BASIC_COLUMN_FAMILY, column);
    }
}
mutator.execute();
```

Well it should look like that. This is an example for insertion, be sure to use the following methods for batch mutations:

```
mutator.addInsertion 
mutator.addDeletion
mutator.addCounter
mutator.addCounterDeletion
```

since this ones will execute right away without waiting for the mutator.execute():

```
mutator.incrementCounter
mutator.deleteCounter
mutator.insert
mutator.delete
```

As a last note: A mutator allows you to batch mutations on multiple rows on multiple column families at once ... which is why I generally prefer to use them instead of CF templates. I have a lot of denormalization for functionalities that use the "push-on-write" pattern of NoSQL.

Comment: I want one clarification: If i want to delete multiple rows then should i get the list of keys first and then try to delete each row key one by one. or there is some other way to delete multiple rows. Because the scenario is something like i don't know the row key(as it generates randomly) but i know the email or some specific column value of each row.

Comment: You should give a look at Reddit for that ... they are at the forefront of use Cassandra from Board/Message/Comment type of data. I would rather use couchbase/bigcouch/couchdb for that. The challenging part with using cassandra would be to get rid of the "read-modify-write", and make any modification a write to cass.

Comment: If you were to post your last comment as a question, I think it would be an interesting exercise for a lot of us.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a batch mutation to insert as much as you want (within thrift_max_message_length_in_mb).  See http://hector-client.github.com/hector//source/content/API/core/1.0-1/me/prettyprint/cassandra/model/MutatorImpl.html.

Comment: I think your mention of the thrift max size is important since if you are not careful it will drop connections. so +1

Comment: Hi Richard can you expound on thrift max size and losing connections. I haven't been hinting max size and I need to know what care I should take.